# Lua Development Tools error module sockets

Tags: lua

I'm using Eclipsse Lua Development Tools to develop Lua aplication but I'm getting an error. I need to add the module Lua Sockets to the Eclipse Lua and when I compile the aplication in the console I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ...eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\sockets\socket.lua:13: module 'socket.core' not found:
no field package.preload['socket.core']
no file '.\socket\core.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\lua\socket\core.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\lua\socket\core\init.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket\core.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket\core\init.lua'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\socket\core.lua'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\socket\core\init.lua'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\socket\core.luac'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\socket\core\init.luac'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\sockets\socket\core.lua'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\sockets\socket\core\init.lua'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\sockets\socket\core.luac'
no file 'C:\eclipse_lua\workspace\sockets\src\sockets\socket\core\init.luac'
no file '.\socket\core.dll'
no file '.\socket\core51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket\core.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket\core51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\socket\core.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\socket\core51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\loadall.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\loadall.dll'
no file '.\socket.dll'
no file '.\socket51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\socket51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\socket.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\socket51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\loadall.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\clibs\loadall.dll'
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

I've downloaded the module scokets in the official lua web page and added this module to the Lua Eclipse. I'm using lua 5.1 in the Eclipse with lua socket 2.0.2 (luasocket-2.0.2-lua-5.1.2-Win32-vc8).

I don't understand what I need to do to solve this error.

Thank you very much

Comment: any reason why you don't follow the installation instructions? http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/installation.html

Comment: The  problem is when I add the lua sockets module to the eclipse I'm getting the error messager mentioned above.

Comment: the error message says that files cannot be found which is a typical error if you did not set the environment variables properly. did you?

Comment: Hello again thank you for your help. I'm not set the environment variables yet, To do that what I have to do??

Comment: so you did not read the installation instructions... you cannot expect things to just work by themselves. there's a reason why people write manuals... you are supposed to read and follow them. read the manual and if you want to know how to set environment variables search the web. there's a million tutorials